# Не могу вывести результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

Dir не выводит мне список атрибутов модуля sys. То ли этот модуль у меня называется иначе, то ли такого модуля в каталоге нет. прошу о помощи

**Mac OS Big Sur 11.3.1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `print` покинул чат:) В примере оно выводится, потому что запущен интерпретатор в интерактивном режиме. Вы же запускаете просто в консоли скрипт

Comment: обратите внимание на >>>

Comment: Благодарю)) на >>> обратил внимание, даже попытался в терминале вывести, но и там не удалось. очевидная ошибка...

Comment: это не ошибка это признак интерактивной консоли питона

Comment: под ошибкой имел в виду print()

Comment: кстати в jupyter notebook можно тоже принт не писать

Comment: да, где-то с месяц назад пользовался именно им, но мне посоветовали пересесть на PyСharm и привыкать к нему

Comment: Измените заголовок вопроса.

Comment: зачем? вопрос ведь уже снят

Comment: для будущих поколений, которые будут пользоваться поиском с такойже проблемой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто забыли вывести через `print()`. В примере функция `dir()` была запущена в интерактивной среде. Если вы введёте в терминале mac "python" и выполните `dir(sys)`, вам выведется результат, даже без `print()`(не забывайте про импорт модуля!) Удачи!